# Remove Bookmark and Reading List Sidebar

Tags: bookmarks, sidebar

Tapping the book icon to the left of the address bar does not remove the Bookmarks/Reading List Sidebar. How does one remove the sidebar?

Comment: Alternatively, the keyboard shortcut for this function is 'shift + command + L'

Answer (score 1):

Move cursor to the top of you screen to reveal menu. Select View and Hide Reading List Sidebar and/or Hide Bookmarks Sidebar.